# How to get continuously updating mouse pointer coordinates without using event handlers in Win UI 3?

Tags: c#, windows, winui-3

```
private void pointerTrigger(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(UIelement);
    }
```

But this triggers only when the event occurs, but I am looking for a method or property that returns this while arbitrarily called.

For UWP this worked :

```
Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().PointerPosition;
```

but in Win UI 3, it gives object not instantiated error.

I am not exactly sure what these are :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.pointerpoint.getcurrentpoint?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-input-pointerpoint-getcurrentpoint(system-uint32)

but if i am not wrong its possible to statically call GetCurrentPoint ?

I assume a MainWindow method or property should have these values

Comment: Using interop is probably the easiest way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610121/how-to-get-cursor-pos-in-a-specific-windows (I agree this all seems overkill)

Comment: Instead of fighting so hard to avoid events, listen to the mouse motion event, **store the position into your own property**, read your property anywhere and everywhere you want.